# FreeBSD-12 IOCage modifying a jail's /root directory

Tags: freebsd, jail, freebsd-ports

What is the reason that copying .bash_profile from the host system into the /root directory of an iocage thin jail does not create a file that is visible to the root user when logged on to that jail?

In other words, if I do this from the host system:

```
cp -p .bash_profile /zroot/iocage/jails/testjail/root/
```

Then `ls -al  /zroot/iocage/jails/testjail/root/.bash_profile` shows that the file exists.

```
ls -al /zroot/iocage/jails/testjail/root/.bash_profile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  3274 Dec 12 15:42 /zroot/iocage/jails/testjail/root/.bash_profile
```

However, when I log on to testjail the file is not visible to the root user:

```
iocage console testjail
ls -a .bash_profile
ls: .bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

If I check the mounts on the host system then amoung other things I see this:

```
zroot/iocage/jails/testjail/root on /zroot/iocage/jails/testjail/root (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
```

Which I believe is the source of my difficulty. How do I put a file into the /root directory of an iocage jail so that it is usable by the root user inside the jail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory `/zroot/iocage/jails/testjail/root/` is not the home directory of the root user; `/zroot/iocage/jails/testjail/root/root/` is.

Answer (score 0):

```
zroot/iocage/jails/testjail/root on /zroot/iocage/jails/testjail/root (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
```

> Q: *"... mounts on the host system ... is the source of my difficulty. How do I put a file into the /root directory of an iocage jail so that it is usable by the root user inside the jail?"*

A: FWIW. A test file created in a similar mount-point

```
zroot/jails/test_01 on /local/jails/test_01 (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
```

```
$ touch /local/jails/test_01/root/TEST-FILE
$ ll /local/jails/test_01/root/TEST-FILE 
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  0 Dec 13 12:56 /local/jails/test_01/root/TEST-FILE
```

is available to root

```
$ ssh admin@test_01
$ sudo su
root@test_01:/home/admin # bash
root@test_01:/home/admin # cd /root
root@test_01:~ # ll /root/TEST-FILE
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  0 Dec 13 11:56 /root/TEST-FILE
```

Notes:

- FreeBSD jails.example.com 12.0-RELEASE FreeBSD 12.0-RELEASE r341666 GENERIC  i386
- Jails created with the [Ansible role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/freebsd_jail).

Comment: Well, I discovered the answer.  `/zroot/iocage/jails/testjail/root` is not the home directory of the root user.  `/zroot/iocage/jails/testjail/root/root` is.  Apparently the iocage design team did not consider the confusion that might result by naming the 'root' of a jail's file system the same as the home directory of the root user.  In any case the mystery is solved.